# How do I update python list without overwriting value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Context:

- Python 3.9
- I have a list `thetas` with 2 values. I initiate this list with some initial values. I intend to update this list in-place for every iteration.
- I have another list `theta_history` where I intend to store the value of `thetas` for every iteration using `update_thetas` function.

Issue:
`theta_history` ends up becoming a list of length = `iterations`, but only the final value of `thetas` repeated instead of the values from each iteration.

Approach (I am using `.append()`, but have also tried using `.insert(ind, val)` - with same results)

```
def update_thetas(thetas):
    for i in range(len(thetas)):
        thetas[i] = thetas[i] + 1
    print(f"thetas: {thetas}")
    return thetas

thetas = [0] * 2
thetas[0] = 10
thetas[1] = 5
theta_history = []
iterations = 3
for i in range(iterations):
    theta_history.append(thetas)
    thetas = update_thetas(thetas)
print(f"theta_history: {theta_history}")
```

This produces:

```
thetas: [11, 6]
thetas: [12, 7]
thetas: [13, 8]
theta_history: [[13, 8], [13, 8], [13, 8]]
```

What I want:

```
theta_history: [[11, 6], [12, 7], [13, 8]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just storing a reference in `theta_history`, so you need to make a copy of the list each time.

You can do a simple copy with the spread operator (`*`). If you were doing something with more complicated innards, you would need to do a deep copy (which you can search online about).

```py
for i in range(iterations):
    theta_history.append([*thetas])
    thetas = update_thetas(thetas)
print(f"theta_history: {theta_history}")
```

Output:

```py
thetas: [11, 6]
thetas: [12, 7]
thetas: [13, 8]
theta_history: [[10, 5], [11, 6], [12, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a copy of the value of `thetas` using `list` or `tuple` function instead of appending a reference to `thetas`.

```
theta_history.append(tuple(thetas))
```

```
foo = ["a", "b", "c"] # original list
bar = foo # a reference to foo
baz = list(foo) # copy value of foo into baz
```